# How change paths to resources in generating by angular-cli css bundle?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-devkit

#### Description

In our angular project based on webpack we use next deploy pipline:
1. Generate all static resources to static folder
2. Generate index html
3. Deploy static resources to "Static server" (S3 bucket)
4. Deploy index.html to "Main server"

Dist folder looks like:

```
dist  
--static  
----anivers-bold.eot  
----logo.svg  
----styles.bundle.css  
----code.bundle.js  
--index.html
```

And links to resources in index.html looks like:
`<script src="http://127.0.0.1:4200/code.bundle.js"></script>`

So, now I generated similar structure and `index.html`, but links in `styles.bundle.css` to fonts and images setup incorrect.
Current: `src: url('anivers-bold.eot');`
Expect: `src: url('http://127.0.0.1:4200/anivers-bold.eot');`

Anyone know how I can change paths to resources in generating by angular-cli css bundle?

#### What I try

You can find test app in [test repository](https://github.com/aksenovdev/test-angular-cli). Use `ng build` for test build

I dive in in angular-cli, and found postcss plugin, that process resources: `node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\plugins\postcss-cli-resources.js`

I try use `resourcesOutputPath` parameter, but it only generating directories. 
Also I try chane href in `base` tag, but in this case angular router break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found next solution:
**In .css file, that was getting from remote server, resources requesting from that server**
So, we need extract styles with resources (background-url, font) in global styles and all will waork